# jquery -ajax not check the boolean value from controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

i have a controller action which is return a boolean result to the jquery.

```
  [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult IsVoucherValid(string voucherCode)
    {
        bool result = false;
        var voucher = new VoucherCode(voucherCode);
        if(voucher.Status==0)
        {
            result = true;
        }
        return Json(result);
    }
```

and call this controller using ajax code

```
    $.ajax({
            url: '/Account/IsVoucherValid?voucherCode=' + code,
            type: 'Get',
            contentType: 'application/json;',
            success: function (data) {
                alert("success");
                if (data) {
                    //if result=true, want to work this
                    $("#person-data").css({ "display": "block" });
                }
            },
            error:alert("error")

        });
```

in the success of ajax the json result is true then want to work the css. but this is not working please help me.

Comment: its working fine for me.... post your html too

Comment: Its `type: 'get',` generally, check what you have. Better to use small though its not syntax error

Comment: are you sure that data.result  is true did you checked that in client side

Comment: @shyama just try use data instead of data.result ?

Comment: Did you do `console.log(data)` to see what `data` contains? Did you watch the traffic on your browser's Network tab? Have you done _any_ debugging?

Comment: and also change "data.result " to "data"

Comment: @Optimus:my problem is that the control is not reached in success, it always goes to error

Comment: what is the error???

Comment: check the network tab of your firebug or whatever tool you are using for debugging you can see the error message there

Comment: @shyama Of course you always get the alert "error". The `alert("error")` is going to execute before the AJAX request even happens. You need to use `error: function () { alert("error"); }` in order to achieve what you are trying to do there.

Comment: @JLRishe: Thank you. I got the output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`result` is a variable name that only exists in that action method. It will not be included in the JSON.

I'm pretty sure that your boolean value will be stored in `data` since you are only sending back a single value:

```
$.ajax({
     url: '/Account/IsVoucherValid?voucherCode=' + code,
     type: 'Get',
     contentType: 'application/json;',
     success: function (data) {
         if (data) {       //if result=true, want to work this                 
             $("#person-data").css({ "display": "block" });
         }
     }
});
```

If in doubt, do `console.log(data)` to see what it contains. You should at least be doing minimal debugging before you bring the question to us.

Also, as @Stephen Muecke points out below, if you are retrieving this data with GET, you need to use:

```
return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: my problem is that the control is not reached in success, it always goes to error

Comment: @shyama Ok, why didn't you tell us that? What is the error? Does the Network tab show any useful information?

Comment: @shyama, Its a GET call, so it needs to be `return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` in the controller (GET calls are denied by default)

Comment: Thank you. I got the output